# Is there a way to make a bindable mxml object?

Tags: apache-flex, binding, mxml

I have an MXML object and I want it to trigger its binding every time one of its properties is updated:

```
<fx:Object id="myObject">
    <fx:prop1>{myButton.selected}</fx:prop1>
    <fx:prop2>value</fx:prop2>
    <fx:prop3>value</fx:prop3>
</fx:Object>

<Button id="myButton" toggle="true" />
<myComponent obj="{myObject}" />
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you want.  The best way I know how to describe it is that binding is only a single level deep; whereas you are trying to make binding two levels deep.

This code:

```
<myComponent obj="{myObject}" />
```

Tells Flex to look at the variable myObject and whenever myObject is changed thenthe obj property on myComponent will also be changed.  It is look at the variable that myObject points to.

This code:

```
<fx:prop1>{myButton.selected}</fx:prop1>
```

Changes a property on myObject; but does not change myObject. myObject is still pointing to the same memory space / variable space.

To get myComponent to change whenever properties on myObject change; I would use a completely different approach.  I would create myObject as an ActionScript class.  Make use of get/set properties and dispatch events whenever a property changes.

Inside of myComponent, you can implement obj as a get/set method.  In your set method add an event listener to the property changes you set up in myObject.  In your event listener method; implement the appropriate changes.

It is not a trivial change from what you're doing; but it shouldn't be too hard either.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be impossible. I added update events to all of my components and made the assignment again (without binding). 10x.

Comment: I can't since it's quite long, but I basically have several toggle buttons to which I've added the same valueCommit handler which generates an object with all of the selected states of my buttons (myObject) and assigns it to myComponent

Comment: Please put together a sample that contains as little code possible to reproduce the problem.  I don't see any other way to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ObjectProxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html).

Example: [Detecting changes to an Object using the Flex ObjectProxy class](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/27/detecting-changes-to-an-object-using-the-flex-objectproxy-class/)

```
private var object:Object = {};
private var objectProxy:ObjectProxy;

objectProxy = new ObjectProxy(object);
objectProxy.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, updateChange);
```

Then, make assignments directly to the proxy:

```
objectProxy.name = "My Object";
```

Comment: Looks interesting. What should I do in the updateChange function? an assignment of the objectProxy to myComponent?

Comment: Yes - data binding.  There are [other examples](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/databinding_pitfalls.html).  ObjectProxy is also how the `ArrayCollection` class handles property change within the collection.

Comment: Making assignments directly to the ObjectProxy proved to be problematic using an MXML Object. I chose a different path but thank you for your help